# Null Reference Exception was unhandeled by user c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nullreferenceexception

I'm Learning to program c# for WP8.

The error is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I'm getting this error and have no idea why, I've used similar code in other classes and it works fine /=

If you need more information let me know, thanks!(=

```
 public partial class DisplayScenario : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    int index;
    private MyDataContext database;
    private ObservableCollection<Questions> questionList;
    public ObservableCollection<Questions> QuestionList
    {
        get
        {
            return questionList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (questionList != value)
            {
                questionList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("QuestionList");
            }
        }
    }

    public void DisplaySceanrio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
      //  QuestionsList.ItemsSource = null;

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("index"))
        {
            string value;

            NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("index", out value);
            index = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);

        } 
        database = new MyDataContext();

        QuestionList = new ObservableCollection<Questions>(from Questions q in database.MyQuestions where q.Id == index select q);
        //Getting error here: vvv
        QuestionsList.ItemsSource = QuestionList;

    }
```

Here's the xaml for the listBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="QuestionsList" ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionList}" SelectionChanged="QuestionTapped" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="QuestionName" Text="{Binding Question, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Where's the event handler called QuestionTapped? If you define a SelectionChanged event handler in your ListBox, it needs to be in your code-behind.

Comment: It's possible that the navigation event is firing before the ListBox is initialized. You should check that QuestionsList isn't null before you try to access its members.

Comment: Thats for the fututre.. It is defeined just nothing int it.. Would that cause this error?

Comment: I have that commented out, when its in the code the debugger stops there with the same error.

Comment: Where exactly does the exception happen, which line?

Comment: QuestionsList.ItemsSource =QuestionList;

Comment: Or here if uncommented: 

QuestionsList.ItemsSource = null;

Comment: QuestionsList is null, obviously, because it's called in the OnNavigatedTo event handler. You can reference it in the page Loaded event handler. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QuestionsList is not yet created when you call the OnNavigatedTo method. It's defined in XAML.

If you used the Loaded event handler, then you know that the ListBox has been created and you can reference it:

```
public DisplayScenario()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += DisplayScenario_Loaded;
}

void DisplayScenario_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    QuestionsList.ItemsSource = QuestionList;
}
```

Also, your constructor has a typo and is never called. It should be DisplayScenario().

```
public DisplayScenario()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Comment: It's still saying QuestionsList is null, and the error is in the same spot.

Comment: @user3034766 your constructor has a typo, and shouldn't return void (or anything for that matter). See the end of my answer.

Comment: OP, your constructor issue is the big problem. The `InitializeComponent();` call is what initializes your UI controls; since your constructor isn't actually a constructor, it's never called and your UI is never initialized

Comment: -facepalm- 

Thanks for the fresh look.

Comment: @user3034766 don't forget to mark as answer if it answers your question.